# How can I download android 2.0 sdk now

Tags: android

How can I download android android 2.0 (not 2.1) sdk now?
I tried 'android sdk and avd manager', it does not have android 2.0 downloadable.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to select Update All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "Android SDK and AVD manager", you can't, but **you can download Android 2.0.1, which differs not that much form 2.0**:

> - New quickContactBadgeStyle* attributes that let applications apply necessary styles to the QuickContactBadge widget.
> - Remove support for the ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED broadcast when declared as a filter in the manifest. To receive this broadcast, an application must do so from the application at run-time, with registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter).

Plus some bugfixes. Take a look at the [API changes overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.1.html#api-changes) and at detailed [API differences report](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/6/changes.html).

Be aware, that it seams that nobody is using 2.0 anymore, take a look at the [Platform Versions report](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any device ever really used 2.0 (there might be a few foreign ones, but none in America that come to mind)

Either use the 1.5, 1.6, or the 2.1 SDK, because those are essentially the only ones that matter unless you need something 2.2 specific

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the 2.0 and 2.0.1 SDKs with the SDK and AVD manager. All you have to do is uncheck "Display updates only" in the "Available Packages" section and you'll see them. However as mentioned above they are labeled obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get 2.0, follow the instructions below.  If not, use 2.1.

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html